# ArrayList указывает на нулевой размер

Tags: android, массивы, listview, arraylist

```
ArrayList<UserDetails> Users;
ArrayList<UserDetails> backUp;
Context context;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
private List<UserDetails> filteredModelItemsArray;
private ModelFilter filter;

ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<UserDetails> Users, Context context)
{
    this.Users = Users;
    this.backUp = new ArrayList<>(Users);

    Log.d("myLog ", getCount() + " " + backUp.size());

    this.context = context;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Есть два массива, первый `Users` это массив который в последствии перебирается и при определенных условиях надо его будет восстановить `backUp` массивом, но проблема в том что не удается заполнить `backUp` массив, при инициализации в лог пишет что и у того и у того массива размер нулевой, но в getView массив `Users` работает, т.е. размер не равен нулю.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View viewItem = view;

    if (view == null)
    {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
    }

    UserDetails user = Users.get(i);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(user.Username);
    if (user.Online)
    {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("Онлайн");
    }
    else
    {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("Оффлайн");
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код метода getView

Comment: @Ksenia обновил

Comment: Добавьте запись из логов, которая выводиться в конструкторе адаптера и код метода `getCount()`.

Comment: я вот смотрю на backUp и вижу что его size = 0, вы его просто создали и все, что вы от него ждете?